# @EnableCaching gets ignored when multiple Junit Tests are run together

Tags: spring-boot, caching, junit5

I have a set of Junit test cases for a Spring Boot application which are annotated with @EnableCaching annotation. When these Junit tests are run individually it works fine. But when run together with the other Junit test classes , the @EnableCaching annotation seems to get ignored.
I'm using the @DirtiesContext annotation to clean the context after each test method. But this doesnt seem to be making any difference to the above mentioned issue.

Please let me know if @EnableCaching can be used in Junit Tests or not.

Please find below a sample code of the Junit Test class.

```
@EnableCaching
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "a,b,c" })
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class SampleTest {

@BeforeEach
void setUpTest() {
        //setup steps

    }
    
@Test
void testCacheable(){   
    String result = controller.testCache();

}


}

@RestController
public class TestController {

@RequestMapping("/testCache")
@Cacheable(cacheNames="cache")
public String testCache() throws InterruptedException {
        logger.info("Returning NOT from cache");
        return "cache";
    }
    
}
```

Comment: post your junit test cases

Comment: The Junit test case has been added